# ValueError: time data '2023-12-10' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

While working with django, I am getting this error with expiry_date field declared as DateField in model. What should I do to resolve the error?

I tried a lot but didn't get the solution. I imported datetime.datetime, etc. but still the error is not resolved.

Comment: You have answer in your error.  You can add to you date string required format like: '2023-12-10 00:00:00:00'

Comment: Or just keep format as `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Are you sure you have a DateField and not a DateTimeField in your model? Can you share the model and the code you are working with?

Comment: @MattSeymour, I have 2 models. Campaign & CampaignDatabase. In 2nd model, I have defined campaign filed as  campaign=models.ForeignKey(Campaign,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True,blank=True),  expiry_date= models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)  where as in the campaign model, I have defined  expiry_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)     I am getting the error in the model itself. Is there can be any issue if we use other fields with datetime format?

Comment: @jeste_artyste, I had tried these methods too but the error was not resolved.

Comment: @Goku, I did the same but still the error is not resolved.

Comment: Can you please update the quetion with the code examples as it makes it easier for everyone to see the complete problem.

Comment: @MattSeymour has a point, we blindly guessing what could happen, give us you data field with all info, code etc, we're not able to help at this point

Comment: The error is resolved, it was coming because I have installed some other versions of the libraries required in my project, which causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is resolved, it was coming because of the conflict between the required or latest versions. Like, I need python 3.7.0 and some other libraries such as importlib-metadata==6.7.0, etc. These versions sometimes create conflicts with latest versions that's why the error came.

Comment: Which *"other versions of the libraries"*?

Comment: Like, I need python 3.7.0 and some other libraries such as importlib-metadata==6.7.0, etc. These versions sometimes create conflicts with latest versions that's why the error came.

Comment: Please, [edit] your answer e put this informations on it